# Make CocoaPods copy resources to specific folder

Tags: cocoa, cocoapods

Before attempting to make my project work with CocoaPods, my project's target copied the resources into a folder structure like:

> Project.app/Resources/deps/javascript/*.js
>   Project.app/Resources/deps/html/index.html

An in my code, I accessed the resources like:

```
NSString *javascriptDirectory = [[bundle pathForResource:@"main" 
                                                  ofType:@"js"                                                       
                                             inDirectory:@"deps/javascript"] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

When creating the CocoaPod spec for the project, I found that CocoaPods dumps resources into the `ProjectUsingCocoaPods.app/Resources` folder.

To make my project work with CocoaPods, I therefore had to modify my code to dump resources into the `Project.app/Resources` folder, and modify accesses to use:

```
NSString *javascriptDirectory = [[bundle pathForResource:@"main" 
                                                  ofType:@"js"] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

My project can now be used via CocoaPods, which is great.

Its resources are unceremoniously dumped into the `Resources` folder however, which is ugly and therefore not so great.

The relevant portion of my CocoaPods spec:

I've got a CocoaPods spec file that specifies some resources that my project needs:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  #...
  s.resource  = ['Project/Dependencies/*.js', 'Project/Dependencies/index.html']
  #...
end
```

**My question is**: is it possible to specify resource subdirectories into which CocoaPods should copy resources?

Answer (score 5):

I found out that specifying a folder as a resource will just create a reference to that folder in the Pods project:

```
s.resources  = "Project/Dependencies"
```

So, there is no any wildcard. The Pods project will have a reference to `Dependencies` folder with all its contents and subfolders as is.